# How do I store values from a SQLite database into an arryOf<String> in Kotlin?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, android-studio

I have a databaseHelper class with which I would like to add a get function which retrieves all values in a column of the database and stores then in an array of strings. I would then like to call this function in a different class.

Below is my "get" function:

```
fun getEmails() {
    val db = readableDatabase
    val select = "$COLUMN_EMAIL"
    val cursor = db.query(EMAIL_TABLE, null, select, null, null, null, null)
    val emails = arrayOf<String>()
    with(cursor) {
        while(moveToNext()) {
            val email = getString(getColumnIndexOrThrow("email"))
            emails.set(cursor.position, email)
        }
    }
    cursor.close()

}
```

Below is the snippet of code where I try to call this function. When I try to pass this into another function, I get a type mismatch error saying "addresses" is a Unit but Array was expected.

```
val addresses = databaseHelper.getEmails()
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to correct this?

Comment: the **`getEmails`** function has not been set to **return** anything. you want  something like `getEmail(): List<String>  {....` and then a statement, after the cusror has been closed, to return emails (the list you have built).